# Artifactory checksums format

Tags: artifactory

It's quite helpful to have the autogenerated checksums, ie, md5sum, sha1, sha256 and sha512 when querying a file, ie:-

```
https://server/artifactory/files/file.txt.md5
https://server/artifactory/files/artifactory/files/file.txt.sha1
https://server/artifactory/files/artifactory/files/file.txt.sha256
```

etc.

My problem is that an downstream system requires the output one would get with the cmd, ie

```
$ md5sum file.txt
3f768759030461237774e050cafea1e3  file.txt
```

or if piped

```
3f768759030461237774e050cafea1e3  -
```

Artifactory only sends the hash itself so the downstream app does not know how to parse it:-

```
3f768759030461237774e050cafea1e3
```

Is there config option, query string or plugin that I can apply so the hash outputs like md5sum, sha1sum, sha256sum and sha512sum, would?

Comment: What is your version of Artifactory? Is it an OSS variant or a PRO one?

Comment: Hi @ajeans, Artifactory Version 5.6.2, I'm using a trial of the Pro Version until we manage to get a license.

Comment: In the meantime, I did a dirty php wrapper. I'll clean it up and post it as an answer later.
`<?php
$checksum = $_GET['checksum'];

// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://localhost/artifactory$checksum");

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

print "$output  ";
echo end(explode('/',$checksum));     
?>`

Comment: If you have a PRO variant, I would recommend that you look at user plugins to achieve nicely what you are looking for. Nice pointers are https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins and https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/. A solution based around _download { altResponse {}}_ would make sense

Comment: sweet, thanks. time to get my groovy on :)